# Idiom for having a strong conviction that turns out to be false

Tags: idioms

Say a scientist believes very firmly in an hypothesis despite limited evidence. After years of research, he stumbles upon a piece of evidence that entirely crushes his ideas. Is there an idiom describing such a development? I want to emphasize the excitement and hope the scientist feels while 'chasing' said idea, as well as the anxiety of finding out that his idea might be wrong.

Comment: Avoid word/phrase requests that lack: (i) objective criteria for accepting answers, including connotation, register, and part of speech; (ii) exact context – generally we want the sentence you’re writing; and (iii) details of research you’ve already done (trips to the thesaurus, etc.) including solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. See: “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity – ELU Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”; “[Real Questions Have Answers – SE Blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”.

Comment: @Kris Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. Avoid answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 0):

**fall into**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/error) idiom

> 4. To undergo a change of state or emotion, especially a negative change

As in:

I took one look at my error and **fell into** a bad mood, excited no more!

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like a balloon-burster to me.

Comment: A good expert answer includes explanation, context, and supporting facts. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the asker, but to future visitors to the page. Please consider expanding your answer.

Expert partial answers are welcome, but notions, trial balloons, offhand ideas, guesses, anecdotes, and general discussion are not answers.